# Adding an express backend to vue-webpack-boilerplate

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

I've just downloaded - [vue-webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) - and the little I've seen of it looks really good :) (first time with webpack + ESlint)

I'm a little confused however - how can I go about adding an express backend to the project?

Not every route is always going to be a vue, sometimes it's an api request or a db call or the like - and if I do hookup an express backend, how can I choose what vue components I want to load?

Am I going about this completely wrong/have misunderstood what this is for?

Thanks

Edit: I've looked at http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/backend.html - but that's not really cleared anything up

Comment: This is an extremely broad question, you need to research the topic more and ask specific questions.

Comment: Sorry it's vague - essentially I have downloaded a really nice build system, that seems to be built only for a single page app (no routing at all). I'm just asking how you'd add routing to something like a vue application.

Comment: Assuming I understand you correct, I would just have seperate html pages and each html page has different vue components. so you could have /purchase is a page and /shoppingcart is another page. These pages have vue components on them that then use ajax to talk to some backend code, in your case your express server.

Comment: Do you want client or server side routing?

Comment: @EricGuan Server-side - I didn't really know client-side was a thing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be confusing with `npm` build packages like `webpack` for front-end with back-end `express` project.

The boilerplate you mention is for front-end. It allow you to develop a static website either with or without [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and end up with `html`, `css` and `js` files to be deployed at any static file hosting.

There is no wrong to make API call anywhere on client-side. E.g. on every route change, you specify what component to load and it can make an API to call to update the UI. That is `SPA` for client-side routing. You just have to make a separate express project for the back-end.

You can try [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) for server-side rendering (SSR). The main advantage for SSR is SEO friendly but not suitable for dynamic page like profile and checkout page. `Nuxt` is a universal (client or server routing) `Vue` app by generating static `html` during run-time. However it is differ than what you think you want to add express API back-end but you can still populate dynamic data with [Async Data](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data)

Check this out [JAMstack](https://jamstack.org/).

Comment: Thanks for that - it was really helpful :)